# Spring websocket Get connection number and details

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I need in my web application to know, when i receive a Stomp message, who is connected to the server via websocket and read the connection details.
what is the class then have this informations and how i can read them?

My implementation in this one:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

and work correctly

thanks for help

Comment: I found a class then give me some information like the number of active clients: WebSocketMessageBrokerStats but i need the connections details

Comment: could you write some example of the type of information you're expecting? And explain in which context you'd use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong approach...
Now when the client connect does a registration message sending the connection details params and the server save that on DB, the client send disconnection message after close the socket and the server make an update...
In this way i have always the number of connections and details stored on DB.